# Iterating over files and stitching together 3D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have several netCDF files that have an array in the shape of (365,585,1386) and I'm trying to read in each new array and stitch them together along axis = 0; or add all of the days of the year (365). The other two dimensions are latitude and longitude, so ideally I have several years of data for each lat/long point (each netCDF file is one calendar year of data).

```py
import glob
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

data = '/Users/sjakober/Documents/ResearchSpring2020/erc_1979.nc'
files = sorted(glob.glob('erc*'))

for x, f in enumerate(files):

    nc = Dataset(data, mode='r')   

    print(f)

    if x == 0:
        a = nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][:]
    else:
        b = nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][:]
        np.hstack((a, b))

    nc.close()
```

Comment: It's best to collect your arrays in a list (with list `append`) and do one `concatenate` at the end.  If you want to join them on a new initial dimension, use `np.array(alist)` or `np.stack`.  Repeated `hstack` is slow.

Comment: The slice operator `[:]` in `nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][:]` is not really needed.

Comment: Another error - `np.hstack` is not like list `append`; it does not operate in-place.  You have to use `c = np.hstack([a, b, d])`, making a new array from joining the ones in the list.

Comment: @accdias, In `x=nc.variables[key][:]`, the [:] is what triggers the load, returning an array.  Without it we just get a `netcdf` `variable` object.  `np.array(nc.variables[key])` might also work (in `h5py` the [:] is more idiomatic).  In any case it isn't as superfluous as it would be with a `ndarray`.

Comment: @hpaulj, It makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. But it wouldn't make more sense to the use objects in functions like `np.hstack()` instead? I don't really know NetCDF so I'm just conjecturing here.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions; I’m going to try and work through it with a list of arrays